# Trying to install rpm package

Tags: linux, installation, rpm, zypper

I am trying to install the GCC 4.7 in linux environment; using following command:

```
zypper install *.rpm
```

in a directory containing:

```
libgcc_s1-4.7.2_20130108-0.17.2.x86_64.rpm 
libmpc2-0.8.2-1.7.1.x86_64.rpm
libstdc++6-4.7.2_20130108-0.17.2.x86_64.rpm
```

Following error shows up:

```
error: Failed to read /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc: Is a directory.
Repository named '_tmpRPMcache_' already exists. Please use another alias.
```

I am not able to find the *tmpRPMcache* where it is located so that I I try to find the issue. Any help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that - when installing rpm files not from a repository - zypper uses a "temporary" repository for those rpms. For some reason that repository already exists. Probably you can find that file in `/etc/zypp/repos.d/` and remove it safely (make a copy just to be sure):

```
mv /etc/zypp/repos.d/_tpmTPMcache_.repo{,.bak}
```

(I'm not 100% sure of the exact filename; but I suspect you will find it there.)

Comment: Thanks Chris , I got the _tmpRPMcache_.repo..But not the exact filename.  I tired but won't work Do you know how to resolve the issue. It would be great if you suggest any solution to ractify the error

Comment: did you just copy the .repo file, or did you also remove the original? (I edited my question to use `mv` instead of `cp`)

Comment: I have delete the _tmpRPMcache_ file from the directory /etc/zypp/repos.d  and trying to install the rpm files but fails stating that error: Failed to read /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc: Is a directory.
Moreover it automatically create an new  _tmpRPMcache_  while trying to install rpm file.

Comment: Can you have any suggestion Chris for this. I would be higly appreciable.

Comment: I'm on holiday now, little access to Internet. I cannot guarantee to find a solution. Seems like the first warming is the true cause: rpmrc is a directory... I'd suggest searching on Google with that. Also comparing with another rpm based is (if you have one at hand) to see what files are present in usr/lib/rpm

Comment: Thanks for your kind response Chris. I'll try to find and let you know once .